# How can I set multiple markers with tsplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, seaborn

I have data on a time-series in a pandas DataFrame and I would like to have separate markers for the lines. So far, I have only managed to use the same marker for both lines by using the `marker='o'` argument.

I'm using the example from http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/timeseries_plots.html#specifying-input-data-with-long-form-dataframes and I've copied my copied and pasted the code below.

How can I plot separate markers for each line?

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(9221999)
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(palette="Set2")


def gamma_pdf(x, shape, coef, obs_err_sd=.1, tp_err_sd=.001):
    y = stats.gamma(shape).pdf(x) * coef
    y += np.random.normal(0, obs_err_sd, 1)
    y += np.random.normal(0, tp_err_sd, len(x))
    return y

gammas = []
n_units = 20
params = [(5, 1), (8, -.5)]
x = np.linspace(0, 15, 31)
for s in range(n_units):
    for p, (shape, coef) in enumerate(params):
        y = gamma_pdf(x, shape, coef)
        gammas.append(pd.DataFrame(dict(condition=[["pos", "neg"][p]] * len(x),
                                        subj=["subj%d" % s] * len(x),
                                        time=x * 2,
                                        BOLD=y), dtype=np.float))
gammas = pd.concat(gammas)

sns.tsplot(gammas, time="time", unit="subj",
           condition="condition", value="BOLD", marker="o")
plt.show()
```

[image: Code Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to either call `tsplot` twice with each level of the `condition` variable, or you can plot this way and then do a post-hoc manipulation of the plot data:

```
ax = sns.tsplot(gammas, time="time", unit="subj",
                condition="condition", value="BOLD", marker="o")
ax.lines[-1].set_marker("s")
```

Comment: I think you should just need to call ax.legend() again and it will update.

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks! Use the `title` parameter to `legend` to get the exact same legend that `seaborn` would have produced:  `ax.legend(title='condition')`